# Tear Down Resource Groups on PR Completion

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, devops, release

I am using Pull Request Builds as outlined below to create a resource group with contained resources

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-pull-request-builds?view=azure-devops

This all works as expected and I am using the SourceBranch of the Pull Request to name by new Resource Group.

My intention is to then delete the Resource Group automatically on completion of the PR. I believed this could be achieved by using another Release pipeline triggered on the build triggered by the PR merge to Master. The issue is that I have no reference to the Branch name in this new Release, the SourceBranch is 'master'

Can anyone come up with a solution? Essentially I need to delete a Resource Group named after a Branch on completion of a PR which merges said branch to master.

There may be multiple PRs in review at any one time so I would prefer that the solution does not queue any stages.

Comment: In PR triggered Release Pipeline , I notice that the variable:`Release.Artifacts.{Primary artifact alias}.SourceBranchName` could directly show the source branch name. Do you mean to find similar variables when the release pipeline is triggered after PR completing?  For *not queue any stages.* , you may try to use the [Artifact filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#env-triggers).

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is that I have no reference to the Branch name in this new Release, the SourceBranch is 'master'

The Pull Request triggered release pipeline is triggered by `refs/pull/x/merge`. This is related with the Pull Request. Then the Pull Request information can be obtained through environment variables.

When the Pull Request Completes, the reason for running the release pipeline is that the master branch has changed. The trigger branch is master.

In this case, the variable `BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME` is master.

Based on my test, I couldn't find the environment variables related to Pull Request Source Branch.

So I am afraid that there is no such variable could meet your requirements.

For a workaround:

If you want to get the expected source branch name , you may need to use the target branch to run the release pipeline again(Manual or Continuous deployment trigger).You need to make sure that the trigger branch is pull request source branch. Then the `BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME` variable could be the expected one.

> not queue any stages.

You could try to set the Artifacts filters (include and exclude) in Release Pipeline stages.

For example:

[image: Filter]

Result:

[image: Result]

Hope this helps.